# How to display a tablewidget in menu command if it is not initiated in Setupui

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

By Menu command, I open an excel file and read its contents, then use a tableWidget to display it.
My question is that if the tableWidget is initiated in def@setupUi it works well. however, I want to create the tableWidget after the excel file being read, it doesn't work.

I have tried to use self.tableWidget.setVisible(False) in def@SetupUi to hide the tableWidget, it does work.
But when I use  self.tableWidget.setVisible(True) in def@fileopenDef to show the tableWidget, it does not work.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap ,QPalette, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringListModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMenu, QPushButton, QWidget, QTableWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QDesktopWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView)
import xlrd
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
from ctypes import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(840, 700)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        #self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        #self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 810, 640))
        #self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        #self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        #self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        #self.tableWidget.hide()
        #self.tableWidget.setVisible(False)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 830, 36))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuView = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuView.setObjectName("menuView")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionSave_as = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_as.setObjectName("actionSave_as")
        self.actionClose = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose.setObjectName("actionClose")
        self.actionDrawPerson = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDrawPerson.setObjectName("actionDrawPerson")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave_as)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionClose)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionDrawPerson)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuView.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.fileopenDef)

    def fileopenDef(self):
        fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open file',
         'c:\\feibo\\doc',"PersonDoc files (*.xlsx)")
        data = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName[0])
        table = data.sheets()[0]
        nrows = table.nrows
        ncols = table.ncols
        #self.tableWidget.setVisible(True)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 400, 10+ncols*100, 20+nrows*40))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(nrows)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(ncols)
        for i in range(nrows):
            for j in range(ncols):
                if isinstance(table.row_values(i)[j], str) == False:
                    newitem = str(table.row_values(i)[j])
                else:
                    newitem = table.row_values(i)[j]
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(newitem)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,newitem)
        #self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        #self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuView.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "View"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionSave_as.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save as"))
        self.actionClose.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))
        self.actionDrawPerson.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "DrawPerson"))


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget=QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui=Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(widget)


    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: every widget should have parent and original `QTableWidget` has parent `self.centralwidget` but in `fileopenDef` you create new `QTableWidget` which  doesn't have parent so window may not know where to display it.

Comment: code gives me error because you use `self.layout` which doesn't exist. Did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error messages ?

Comment: hi furas, I'm a newer in python. 'self.layout' is not necessary.

Comment: so could you give me an example to realize this function? thank you!

Comment: when I use `self.centralwidget = MainWindow` instead of `self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)` then I can hide and show again `QTableWidget` created in `setupUi`

Answer (score 0):

When I use

```
self.centralwidget = MainWindow
```

instead of

```
self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
```

then I can hide and show again `QTableWidget` created in `setupUi`

I think `QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)` creates widget inside widget and later program has problem to correctly recognize where to display `QTableWidget`. But I can't confirm it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap ,QPalette, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringListModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMenu, QPushButton, QWidget, QTableWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QDesktopWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView)
import xlrd
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
from ctypes import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(840, 700)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        #self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget = MainWindow
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 810, 640))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        #self.tableWidget.hide()
        self.tableWidget.setVisible(False)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 830, 36))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuView = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuView.setObjectName("menuView")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionSave_as = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_as.setObjectName("actionSave_as")
        self.actionClose = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose.setObjectName("actionClose")
        self.actionDrawPerson = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDrawPerson.setObjectName("actionDrawPerson")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave_as)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionClose)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionDrawPerson)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuView.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.fileopenDef)

    def fileopenDef(self):
        fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open file',
         'c:\\feibo\\doc',"PersonDoc files (*.xlsx)")
        data = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName[0])
        table = data.sheets()[0]
        nrows = table.nrows
        ncols = table.ncols

        self.tableWidget.setVisible(True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(nrows)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(ncols)

        for i in range(nrows):
            for j in range(ncols):
                if isinstance(table.row_values(i)[j], str) == False:
                    newitem = str(table.row_values(i)[j])
                else:
                    newitem = table.row_values(i)[j]
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(newitem)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,newitem)
        #self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        #self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuView.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "View"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionSave_as.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save as"))
        self.actionClose.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))
        self.actionDrawPerson.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "DrawPerson"))

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(widget)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**EDIT:** To create `QTableWidget` in `fileopenDef` I have to do three things:

I have to show it

```
self.tableWidget.show()
```

because `tableWidget` is created after executing `widget.show()` (at the bottom of code) which probably shows all widgets inside `widget` which is used as `MainWindow`.

But then it shows `QTableWidget` in separated window - because it doesn't have `parent`. So second thing is to set `self.centralwidget` as parent for `QTableWidget` (like it was in `QTableWidget` created in `Ui_MainWindow`)

```
self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget) # parent
```

And then it stop showing it  but when I change

```
self.centralwidget = MainWindow
```

then it shows `QTableWidget` in main window. That's all.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap ,QPalette, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringListModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMenu, QPushButton, QWidget, QTableWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QDesktopWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView)
import xlrd
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
from ctypes import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(840, 700)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        #self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget = MainWindow
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 830, 36))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuView = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuView.setObjectName("menuView")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionSave_as = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_as.setObjectName("actionSave_as")
        self.actionClose = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose.setObjectName("actionClose")
        self.actionDrawPerson = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDrawPerson.setObjectName("actionDrawPerson")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave_as)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionClose)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionDrawPerson)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuView.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.fileopenDef)

    def fileopenDef(self):
        fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open file',
         'c:\\feibo\\doc',"PersonDoc files (*.xlsx)")
        data = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName[0])
        table = data.sheets()[0]
        nrows = table.nrows
        ncols = table.ncols
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget) # parent
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 810, 640))
        #self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 10+ncols*100, 20+nrows*40))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(nrows)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(ncols)
        self.tableWidget.show() # show it because it is executed after `widget.show()` at the bottom of code

        for i in range(nrows):
            for j in range(ncols):
                if isinstance(table.row_values(i)[j], str) == False:
                    newitem = str(table.row_values(i)[j])
                else:
                    newitem = table.row_values(i)[j]
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(newitem)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,newitem)
        #self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        #self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuView.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "View"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionSave_as.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save as"))
        self.actionClose.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))
        self.actionDrawPerson.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "DrawPerson"))


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget=QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui=Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(widget)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but what I'm more interested in is how to create tablewidget in def@fileopenDef, not in def@setupui. could you give me an example?

Comment: you have it in second code which I put few minutes ago.